# Comparing date in python and applying a condition on comparison

Tags: python, date, date-comparison, delta

i want to compare/subtract two date's due date from current date in python and apply a condition on this subtraction that if the difference is >0 days then calculate fine by multiplying difference with fine per day

```
from datetime import date

a=date.today()

issuedate=date(2019,5,9)

duedate#should be 5 days after issue date i can't find the method for doing this 

check=a-duedate

#  if check>0days:
#   print(check days*40)
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the timedelta function in the datetime module:

```
from datetime import date
import datetime

a=date.today()

issuedate=date(2019,5,9)

duedate = issuedate+datetime.timedelta(days=5)

check=a-duedate
print(check>=datetime.timedelta(days=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use timedelta

from datetime import timedelta

```
duedate = issuedate + timedelta(days=5)

check=(a-duedate).days
```